# How to call a function right after clicking on the back button of router-flux?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using `react-native-router-flux` version `3.38.0`. When I click on the back button on the router-header, I need to call an action creator or a function. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `renderBackButton` props on your router flux `Scene` component. With this props, you have to call a closure / function to implement your custom back button.

```
import LeftButton from '...';

...

<Scene
  key="yourSceneKey"
  component={YourSceneComponent}
  title="Your Scene Title"
  renderBackButton={() => 
    <LeftButton 
      leftButtonIcon={"arrow-back"} 
      onLeft={() => Actions.pop()} 
      leftButtonColor={"white"} 
      leftButtonIconSize={30} 
    />
  }
/>
```

Ref: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/v3/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md